# Upload files ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-uploading

Im using ASP.NET web forms and C#.
I want to upload images to a specific folder and to rename the file to some name
and not to upload the file if its not a PNG.
I dont have a clue how to do it, some help please?

Comment: There are multiple resources on the web for doing this... Check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167240/asp-net-file-upload) and this (http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/)

Comment: This is a big vague.  What have you tried?  There are plenty of tutorials online on how to upload things.  And checking the file extension of the uploaded file is really simple.  I think this question is too vague to get a real answer, short of someone simply writing a solution for you.

Comment: Try google: https://www.google.com/search?q=upload+file+in+asp.net+C%23+web+form+%2B+stackoverflow+site:stackoverflow.com&biw=1366&bih=621&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizqPm5q67yAhUPgP0HHVNKCfwQrQIoBHoECAUQBQ

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but did you even try googling?

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1757/File-Upload-with-ASP-NET
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx
- http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/

For checking if the file is PNG:

- [determine if file is an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670546/determine-if-file-is-an-image)
- [C# How can I test a file is a jpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772388/c-sharp-how-can-i-test-a-file-is-a-jpeg)

Comment: Im trying to do it without ASP.NET Controls

Comment: I tried this code
            if (Request.Form.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["file"];

            //check file was submitted
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("../images/airports", fname)));
            }
        }
and its not working, i dont get any error but the file is not uploaded