# how to browse the images and insert it into DIV in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Its an asp.net web application.In this,i just want to browse an image and i want to display that image within the DIV.

Comment: Please elaborate. I'm sure, nobody'd have understood your question!

Comment: Add your HTML code here

Comment: Place an Image control inside DIV element and then set its source property with your Image path + name.

Comment: Its an asp.net web application.In this i just want to browse an image and i want to display within a DIV.dats it

Comment: @Boopathi what about jquery? Would the answer be acceptable?

Comment: And please add HTML a bit.

Comment: K give me the ans.whatever suits whether jquery or something else

Comment: @Boopathi: Your question is not clear enough. please try to explain more. at least post an image to show what you want, if you don't have any code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want the user to select a file, upload it and display on page.

You are looking for a file upload: [ASP.NET File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167240/asp-net-file-upload)

After, you just need to insert a IMG tag poiting to the file you have saved on server:

```
<asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server"
       AlternateText="Image text"
       ImageUrl="uploads/image1.jpg"/>
```

Another way, using Ajax:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/ajaxfileupload/ajaxfileupload.aspx

Comment: But i want it to browse and then upload