# Upload/download files from client to server

Tags: c#, upload

I am trying to have a C# app upload files to a remote server folder.

I don't want to install any software on the client side, but somehow upload the file to a place where the server can read it.

The server can have any software installed.

Is there any way to upload/download using C# to some online free web storage?

I tried dropbox, box etc but they all can download using a link and not upload.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you have a server that you store the files on, it's actually easier to just create a small asp.net website. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167240/asp-net-file-upload explains how to do this.

I really don't recommend doing uploads to a server using a client-side program, because it means you also need to deal with connecting to your server, which means dealing with firewall access and HTTP handlers to receive your file. And any C# app will have to install stuff.

Comment: I don't have any server. I have a manager app and many clients, and I just need to get a simple xml file from the client. I wanted a shared folder on the manager PC to copy the files into, but I did not succeed to access it because it is not in domain. no somple solution to upload a file to some free storage (url, user name and pass)?