# Upload file to folder with javascript verification check - ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-8

I have been pounding my head on this issue for several days and could use some help, maybe a fresh set of eyes would help.

I have Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.0 and ASP.NET 4.5.  I am new to both IIS and ASP.NET so please be patient with me.  The website I am trying to build allows the user to upload files which will first be checked to make sure they are valid and then will be placed on a folder on the web server.

I tried having the Javascript validate the inputs first before submitting the form to the server.  However, nothing is uploaded so I decided to do one step at a time and just do a simple upload (without Javascript validation, for now).

Here is currently how the files stand:

**upload_page.aspx**

```
<html>
...
<script language="Javascript">
    function validate()
    {
        var filter = <allowed file extensions>;
        var file1 = document.getElementById("uploadfile1").value;
        //do the checks

        if(filter.test(file1))
        {
            returnval = true;
        }
        else
        {
            returnval = false;
        }

        return returnval;
    }
</script>
...
<body>
    <form method="post" runat="server" name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="uploadfile1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" onClientClick="btnUpload_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload_page.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.uploadfile1.HasFile)
    {
        this.uploadfile1.SaveAs("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\uploaded_files\\" + this.uploadfile1.FileName);
    }
}
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Where's the `action` for the `form`?

Comment: Actually, you have nothing in your `form` to `submit` it.

Comment: Well, I am confused because I had taken it out due to the answers in questions like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569565/uploading-files-in-asp-net-without-using-the-fileupload-server-control) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167240/asp-net-file-upload).  In any case, I put it back in as `action="upload_page.aspx"` and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some incorrect thing in code, like using `onClientClick` for server button click event . You can use `PostedFile` in `this.uploadfile1.save..`.

**Correct Complete code**

ASPX Part

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload_page.aspx">
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="uploadfile1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Code behind

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (uploadfile1.HasFile)
    {
        string rootpath = @"D:\webfile\";
        uploadfile1.PostedFile.SaveAs(rootpath + uploadfile1.PostedFile.FileName);
    }
}
```

Replace  `rootpath` with required value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I made your changes but I do get an error, though.  'btnUpload_Click' is not a member of 'ASP_upload_page_aspx'

Comment: @noblerare, make sure you have single copy of `btnUpload_Click` , and clean, rebuild your solution, just to make sure , there is no compilation error.

Comment: I checked and double-checked everything but just couldn't get the `.cs` file to work.  I ended up just putting the relevant code within `<script>` tags of the `.aspx` file and it worked like a charm.