# Upload & Download File with Asp.net / c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, postback

I'm looking for a way to upload and download a file to a server.
Only a selection with an upload button (my code uses an upload panel)
Here is the list of all methods i have tried.

- asp.net fileUpload control but It's losing content when I click on the Upload Button (due to Postback).
- store fileUpload on Session.
- use AsyncFileUpload
- Use postback trigger

But it's not working, do you have any tips or ideas ?

Comment: What kind of web application are you developing? Web Forms or MVC?
In any case, hope these links help. ## UPLOAD A FILE ##
In case of **Web Forms** take a look at this link:
[Upload File in Web Forms pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167240/asp-net-file-upload) In case of **MVC** take a look at this instead:
[Upload a file on a MVC web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0) ## DOWNLOAD A FILE ##
In case of **Web Forms**:
[Download file with web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477398/asp-net-file-download-from-server) In case of **MV

Comment: Gogle:  https://www.google.com/search?q=upload+file+in+asp.net+C%23+web+form+%2B+stackoverflow+site:stackoverflow.com&biw=1366&bih=621&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizqPm5q67yAhUPgP0HHVNKCfwQrQIoBHoECAUQBQ